# weblogic thread monitoring shows incorrect number vs OS threads

Tags: java, multithreading, pthreads, weblogic

Just doing some debugging on my application, noticed a pretty big discrepency. Weblogic is reporting (Servers > Monitoring > Threads) at 6

But when I query the OS:

`ps -eLF|  grep user | grep -c java`

linux shows 37+ threads... So my first question is, why the discrepancy? My second question is how can I get more info why those threads were started from os?

The reason why I'm asking is that I am running out of resources on the OS and I'm trying to figure out clever ways to optimize container without touching applications deployed on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to obtain a thread dump from the JVM.  There are many management threads:

- Compiler threads (for generating machine code)
- Garbage collector threads (often one thread per core)
- Finalization queue processing threads
- JMX management listener

Weblogic might also maintain a thread pool and the reported number probably does not include the number of dormant threads in the pool.

Comment: Is there any way to tune at least some of the threads used by the container? a good dozen (12) of them are:  "[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: 'x' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)" I would really like to find a way to reduce the total number of threads, even by 20-25%

Comment: I would consult resources on Websphere tuning. I found this [resource on thread pool tuning](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0909_blythe/0909_blythe.html#sec3b). I don't know how useful it is, sorry.